# Issue with Shared Preferecne logic in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android development and I am developing my first Android app in which I am using the concept of Shared preferences to store the value of a button.

**My requirement** :

When the app is opened for the very first time since installation , the user clicks on the button and a timer picker dialog opens. The user selects the preferred time and clicks 'OK' button. After clicking the 'OK' button , the time selected by user is set as text on the button itself. So now the button displays the time set by the user. I want this value to be available whenever the user opens the app apart from first time.

In order to save that button value, I am using shared preference. Hence whenever the user opens the main activity apart from first time, the button displays the value of time selected previously by the user.

On the below code, I have implemented shared preference with the knowledge I have and I tried running my app. When the app is opened for the first time, in the main activity I set the value of time and that time is displayed correctly on the button.

**Problem Faced :**

When I press the back button(On Stop()) or remove the app from memory by hitting the recent apps button(On Destroy()) and open my app again , the time value on button is available as selected by user previously. Now when I close the app without setting any time and open the app again the button the value displayed previously in is replaced by the default text (i.e. "Set time") .
The problem is when I don't set time and close app , the value in button resets when the app is opened again.

I am not able to understand why the shared preference doesn't work properly from the second time onwards.

Someone please help me in correcting the below code. Thanks in advance :)

**Note :** the imports for the class and layout xml file is not included below.

**My Code:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SharedPreferences storedata;

    public static final String filename = "StoredData";



    Button ATfrom;

    int ATfromHour;
    int ATfromMinute;

    static long ATfrom_to_millisec;

    String Active_From_Time;

    String SP_Active_From_Time = null;



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();
        storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storedata.edit();
        editor.putString("Active_From_Time", Active_From_Time);

        editor.commit();

    }

        @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
            storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storedata.edit();
            editor.putString("Active_From_Time", Active_From_Time);

            editor.commit();
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onRestart();
        storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SP_Active_From_Time = storedata.getString("Active_From_Time", "Set time");

        ATfrom.setText(SP_Active_From_Time);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume(); 
        storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SP_Active_From_Time = storedata.getString("Active_From_Time", "Set time");


    ATfrom.setText(SP_Active_From_Time);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SP_Active_From_Time = storedata.getString("Active_From_Time", "Set time");

        ATfrom.setText(SP_Active_From_Time);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ATfrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ATfrom);
        ATfrom.setOnClickListener(this);



        //calling shared preference to get the value of the button ATfrom

        storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SP_Active_From_Time = storedata.getString("Active_From_Time", "Set time");


        ATfrom.setText(SP_Active_From_Time);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String statetosave = ATfrom.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putString("saved_state", statetosave);


        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        String statesaved = savedInstanceState.getString("saved_state");
        ATfrom.setText(statesaved);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.ATfrom:

            final Calendar ATfromC = Calendar.getInstance();
            ATfromHour = ATfromC.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            ATfromMinute = ATfromC.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog ATfromtpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            String AM_PM;
                            if (hourOfDay < 12) {
                                AM_PM = "AM";
                            } else {
                                AM_PM = "PM";
                                if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                                    hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                                }
                            }
                            if (minute < 10) {
                                ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":0" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                            } else {
                                ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                            }

                            //Converting time to string for shared preference
                            Active_From_Time = ATfrom.getText().toString();

                            ATfrom_to_millisec = (ATfromHour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (ATfromMinute * 60 * 1000);


                        }
                    }, ATfromHour, ATfromMinute, false);


            ATfromtpd.show();

            break;
                  }


    }
}
```

Comment: the logic u have used to save the shared preference is wrong. During the second launch of the activity (i.e immediate launch after setting the time) the value of Active_From_Time is null and the same will be saved in onDestroy/OnStop callback. i would suggest u to save time value to shared preferences once time selected inside onTimeSet()  and get the value from shared preferences in onCreate as u have done.

Comment: don't save values to shared preferences in `onStop` and `onDestroy` they are getting overrided due to this

Comment: Understood.Thanks for making it clear Ramesh and Vivek :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your onStop and onDestroy method is not required. Remove onStop and onDestroy and update your click listener like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.ATfrom:

            final Calendar ATfromC = Calendar.getInstance();
            ATfromHour = ATfromC.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            ATfromMinute = ATfromC.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog ATfromtpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            String AM_PM;
                            if (hourOfDay < 12) {
                                AM_PM = "AM";
                            } else {
                                AM_PM = "PM";
                                if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                                    hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                                }
                            }
                            if (minute < 10) {
                                ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":0" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                            } else {
                                ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                            }

                            //Converting time to string for shared preference
                            Active_From_Time = ATfrom.getText().toString();

                            ATfrom_to_millisec = (ATfromHour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (ATfromMinute * 60 * 1000);
    storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storedata.edit();
                editor.putString("Active_From_Time", Active_From_Time);

                editor.commit();

                        }
                    }, ATfromHour, ATfromMinute, false);


            ATfromtpd.show();

            break;
                  }


    }
```

As everytime you launch your app and exit Active_From_Time value get override and updated in shared preference.

Happy coding !!!

Comment: Your elaborate answer along with the code was really helpful in understanding. Thanks for your answer and time Anjali :)